# Java Create new Object using groupedBy with different variables

Tags: java, java-stream

I'm trying to figure out how to use groupedBy correctly. I have a List with grades, deviations and subjects. Deviation and Grade are returned in the same field and can be differentiated by type

| subject | grade_date | grade | type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Math | 2022-03-01 | 1 | g |
| Math | 2022-03-01 | 0.5 | d1 |
| Math | 2022-03-01 | 0.5 | d2 |
| German | 2022-03-02 | 2 | g |
| German | 2022-03-02 | 0.3 | d1 |
| German | 2022-03-02 | 0.2 | d2 |
| German | 2022-05-01 | 1 | g |
| German | 2022-05-01 | 0.5 | d1 |
| German | 2022-05-01 | 0.4 | d2 |

My goal is it to group this list by Subject and create a new Object which looks like this.

```
public class MapObject {
    private String subject;
    List<Grade> g = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Grade> d1 = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Grade> d2 = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Grade Object would look like this

```
public class Grade {
        private Float grade;
        private LocalDate gradeDate;
    }
```

And the result (in JSON) should look like this

```
[
    {
        "subject": "Math",
        "g": [
            {
                "grade": 1.0,
                "gradeDate": "2022-03-01",
            }
        ],
        "d1": [
            {
                "grade": 0.5,
                "gradeDate": "2022-03-01",
            }
        ],
        "d2": [
            {
                "grade": 0.5,
                "gradeDate": "2022-03-01",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "subject": "German",
        "g": [
            {
                "grade": 2.0,
                "gradeDate": "2022-03-02",
            },
            {
                "grade": 1.0,
                "gradeDate": "2022-05-01",
            }
        ],
        "d1": [
            {
                "grade": 0.3,
                "gradeDate": "2022-03-02",
            },
            {
                "grade": 0.5,
                "gradeDate": "2022-05-01",
            }
        ],
        "d2": [
            {
                "grade": 0.2,
                "gradeDate": "2022-03-02",
            },
            {
                "grade": 0.4,
                "gradeDate": "2022-05-01",
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I tried to use the groupedBy as follow but I couldn't figure out how to split the lists to g[], d1[], d2[]

```
var temp = myList.stream()
           .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(SourceEntity::getSubject,
                    Collectors.mapping(s -> {
                       return new Grade(s.getGrade(), s.getGradeDate());
                    }, Collectors.toList())))
           .entrySet()
           .stream()
           .map(x -> new MapObject(x.getKey(), x.getValue()))
           .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the *downstream collector* of `groupingBy()` you need to provide a *collector* which associate each *type* with a list of *grades*.

For that, you can either use another *collector* `groupingBy()` and pass a combination of `mapping()` + `toList()` as its downstream (*as already shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73911845/17949945)*), or create a *custom collector* for that purpose.

In order to transform a `Map<String,List<Grade>>` (*grades by type*) into a `MapObject` you can introduce a utility method.

```
List<SourceEntity> myList = // initializing the list
        
List<MapObject> temp = myList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        SourceEntity::getSubject,
        Collector.of(
            HashMap::new,
            (Map<String, List<Grade>> gradesByType, SourceEntity next) ->
                gradesByType.computeIfAbsent(next.getType(), k -> new ArrayList<>())
                .add(new Grade(next.getGrade(), next.gradeDate)),
            (left, right) -> {
                right.forEach((k, v) -> left.merge(k, v,
                    (oldV, newV) -> { oldV.addAll(newV); return oldV; }));
                return left;
            })
    ))
    .entrySet().stream()
    .map(entry -> MapObject.of(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()))
    .toList();
```

```
public class MapObject {
    public static final String GRADE = "g";
    public static final String DEVIATION_1 = "d1";
    public static final String DEVIATION_2 = "d2";
    
    private String subject;
    private List<Grade> g = Collections.emptyList();
    private List<Grade> d1 = Collections.emptyList();
    private List<Grade> d2 = Collections.emptyList();
    
    // constructors getters
    
    public static MapObject of(String subject, Map<String, List<Grade>> gradesByType) {
        
        return new MapObject(subject,
            gradesByType.getOrDefault(GRADE, Collections.emptyList()),
            gradesByType.getOrDefault(DEVIATION_1, Collections.emptyList()),
            gradesByType.getOrDefault(DEVIATION_2, Collections.emptyList())
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `groupBy` twice - once by subject, and once by type. This way, the different types are put into a map, and you can easily extract them as lists using `get("g")`, `get("d1")`, etc.

```
// Map<String, Map<String, List<Grade>>>
var map = list.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
    x -> x.getSubject(),
    Collectors.groupingBy(
        x -> x.getType(),
        Collectors.mapping(x -> new Grade(x.getGrade(), x.getGradeDate()), Collectors.toList())
    )
));
```

Then you can transform each entry into a `MapObject`:

```
var result = map.entrySet().stream().map(MapObject::fromMapEntry).toList();
```

where

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class Grade {
    private Float grade;
    private LocalDate gradeDate;
}

@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
class MapObject {
    private String subject;
    private List<Grade> g;
    private List<Grade> d1;
    private List<Grade> d2;

    private MapObject() {}

    public static MapObject fromMapEntry(Map.Entry<String, Map<String, List<Grade>>> entry) {
        var mapObject = new MapObject();
        mapObject.subject = entry.getKey();
        mapObject.g = Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(entry.getValue().get("g"), ArrayList::new);
        mapObject.d1 = Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(entry.getValue().get("d1"), ArrayList::new);
        mapObject.d2 = Objects.requireNonNullElseGet(entry.getValue().get("d2"), ArrayList::new);
        return mapObject;
    }
}
```